# Record cannot be inserted in table with Integer Primary Key field

Tags: java, jdbc, sqlite, sqlexception

I have a table in SQLite database with its ID field as `integer primary key` (hence `autoincrement`ed ). I have following query to insert the record in the table.

```
INSERT INTO users(fname, lname, email, password) VALUES('Foo','Bar','foo@bar.com','12345');
```

While the first field `u_id` is omitted. This query runs fine from terminal and I'm able to insert record, but doing so from Java throws `SQLException` with message `users.u_id may not be NULL`. I'm using `PreparedStatement` with following query:

```
INSERT INTO users(fname, lname, email, password) VALUES(?,?,?,?)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

**Note:**
I'm using SQLite 3, with JDBC driver [SQLiteJDBC](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:sm3IEtsiaxsJ:www.zentus.com/sqlitejdbc/%20&cd=4&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=in) (the site is closed but I do have the `jar` file downloaded earlier). Is it something to do with drivers?

### Update:

Here's stack trace of exception thrown:

```
java.sql.SQLException: users.u_id may not be NULL
at org.sqlite.DB.execute(DB.java:275)
at org.sqlite.DB.executeUpdate(DB.java:281)
at org.sqlite.PrepStmt.executeUpdate(PrepStmt.java:77)
at com.paperfood.DatabaseManager.insertUser(DatabaseManager.java:64)
at com.paperfood.controller.RegisterUser.doPost(RegisterUser.java:62)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

And following is my record insertion Java code:

```
PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO users(fname, lname, email, password) VALUES(?,?,?,?)");
pst.setString(1, user.getFirstName());
pst.setString(2, user.getLastName());
pst.setString(3, user.getEmail());
pst.setString(4, user.getPassword());
pst.executeUpdate();
```

Where, `user` is object of entity class with fields mapped to table fields. Also, note that my controller (`RegisterUser` servlet) is using `DatabaseManager` class to insert record and the `DatabaseManager` class has method `insertUser()` which accepts argument of entity class' object of class `User`.

Following is SQL to create table `users`:

```
CREATE TABLE users(
    u_id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    fname varchar(30),
    lname varchar(30),
    email varchar(30),
    password varchar(32)
);
```

Comment: Post full stack trace with error code

Comment: please post some relevant java code where you create the query and try inserting

Comment: Does it work if you use `pst.execute();` instead of `pst.executeUpdate();` ? Moreover, what exactly are the `String`s of `user` that you set? Maybe they contain sql keywords.

Comment: Doesn't work with `execute()` as well, string within the `user` are usual names and doesn't contain any SQL keywords.

Comment: Can you post the statement you use to create the table?

Comment: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.db.sqlite.jdbc/854 Please check if you're pointing to right database in your code.

Comment: @SenthilKumar: If I were pointing wrong database, how the stack trace would know that something's wrong with `users` table? and I have only single `users` table in my `.sqlitedb` file.

Comment: as said in the referred post, different database which has the same column names but primary field is not set to autoincrement. you might have a test db or something. i couldn't find anything wrong in the code.

Comment: Try adding a `NOT NULL` to your primary key in the create statement.

Comment: @Baz: Tried adding `NOT NULL`, doesn't work either. This is really bugging and I'm suspecting the drivers now. I'm on Linux, what other platform independent drivers I have for SQLite 3?

Comment: @Kush Have you tried the link in the comment to `Senthil Kumar`s answer? Try version 3.7.2 That's the one I am using on Linux.

Comment: @Baz: Replaced the driver, and have posted comment to SenthilKumar's answer what I'm facing now. :-/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO users(u_id, fname, lname, email, password) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)");

pst.setString(1, null);
pst.setString(2, user.getFirstName());
pst.setString(3, user.getLastName());
pst.setString(4, user.getEmail());
pst.setString(5, user.getPassword());
```

According to [this](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html), setting it as null should work.

> If no ROWID is specified on the insert, or if the specified ROWID has a value of NULL, then an appropriate ROWID is created automatically.

I'm not sure why your code didn't work although it is correct according to the first part of the above statement.

**EDIT:**

Just ran into [this](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.db.sqlite.jdbc/854%20Please%20check%20if%20you%27re%20pointing%20to%20right%20database%20in%20your%20code.). Please check if you're pointing to the right database in your code.

Comment: Tried, getting same exception. (btw, you have 6 question marks in SQL query rather than 5).

Comment: Ran command `.databases` on my SQLiteDB file, and there's only `main` database with `users` table, how can I make sure I'm pointed to this table within main database?

Comment: cool, if wrong table, then, it would have said table doesn't exist. Also, just went through this long discussion http://www.experts-exchange.com/Database/Miscellaneous/Q_27506454.html, same jdbcdriver and he finally managed to insert only by inserting primary key by himself, am more curious now to know what is that going wrong!

Comment: Since it works on command line and related discussion on other sites, i've come to a conclusion that the diver is bad, you may try this http://www.xerial.org/trac/Xerial/wiki/SQLiteJDBC :)

Comment: I'm using version 3.7.2 and I'm not having any problems with that version.

Comment: @SenthilKumar: Replaced the driver with one you suggested, also added `NOT NULL` to the id field as suggested by @Baz, but now getting SQLException with message `[SQLITE_CONSTRAINT]  Abort due to constraint violation (users.u_id may not be NULL)`

Comment: @Kush Did you set the id to `null` as suggested in this answer? If so, delete that. It conflicts with `NOT NULL` of table creation. Just remove the id from the `INSERT` statement. Alternatively, remove `NOT NULL` and try the version in this answer.

Comment: @Baz: tried both ways, keeping `NOT NULL` of table creation and removing `null` from INSERT, as well as removing `NOT NULL` from table, and keeping `null` in INSERT, stuck at the same exception `[SQLITE_CONSTRAINT] Abort due to constraint violation (users.u_id may not be NULL)`, Do I have only solution left is to remove autoincrement, or switch to MySQL at least for now?

Comment: @Kush Can't really tell what's going wrong... Works fine for me with somehow similar code... Sorry I couldn't help. MySQL might be quite an overhead depending on the scale of your application. Maybe try setting up a new project with a minimal setup to try the driver and the statements...

Comment: @Baz: Yes MySQL will be an overkill, I've worked with SQLite previously, just this insertion in Autoincremented field is new for me (in case of SQLite), and don't know what's so wrong. :-/

Answer (score 0):

Your current primary key is not autoincrement, so you need to specify the value of the primary key yourself. If you want the primary key to be autoincrement, you need to specify it explicitly.

See: http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html Your table definition would need to be:

```
CREATE TABLE users(
    u_id integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    fname varchar(30),
    lname varchar(30),
    email varchar(30),
    password varchar(32)
);
```

Comment: That's what I thought, too. I always use the `AUTOINCREMENT` keyword, but after I read the link you supplied, I'm not sure, it is necessary for an `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`. The text says, that adding a `AUTOINCREMENT` will alter the algorithm used for the key generation, but even without the `AUTOINCREMENT`, each row will get its unique id automatically.

Comment: I tried exact same table creation query, but still can't get the issue fixed.

Comment: @Kush Did you try creating a new minimal project just to test the driver and sql statements?